# How to carry out expansion in regular expression problems like ((0*10)*)?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I have been given some problems like:

Determine if each of the following strings belongs to the corresponding regular language.

i. ‘10100010’ and L((0*10)*).

iv. ‘011100101’ and L(01*10*(11*0)*)

I just wanted to know the strategy to answer such questions. Show me the working for two of them. Thanks.

Comment: Build a DFA from the regular expression. There are completely mechanical ways to do that. Feed the string to the DFA and see if you end up in an accepting state.

Comment: Are you asked to just give a yes/no answer or to produce a proof?

Comment: Proof gives me a direction.